# Time Machine: disk was not ejected properly

Tags: time-machine, usb

I have an external hard drive (Verbatim #47576) setup as a Time Machine drive.

Everyday, at random intervals, the computer warns me that the disk was not ejected properly. Why? How to prevent that? Is there a real problem?

iMac8,1 , MacOS X 10.6.7, Darwin 10.7.0,

Comment: Similar: [*Disk not ejected properly message since started to use El Capitan*](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/224632/17907)

Answer (score 3):

This happens because of a USB Sleep issue with some external usb devices. This happens when the USB disk is put on sleep.

Some people claim that this problem is solved by disabling **Put the hard disk(s) to sleep when possible** in the `Energy Saver` preferences pane.

Comment: I wonder, is there some way to only disable the *external* drive from sleeping?

Comment: Where is that "Put the hard disk(s) to sleep when possible" checkbox in modern macOS Sonoma etc. edition of the System Settings?