# Where is that "Put the hard disk(s) to sleep when possible" checkbox in modern macOS Sonoma etc. edition of the System Settings?

Tags: macos, power-management, sonoma, system-settings

I would like to turn off the "Put the hard disk(s) to sleep when possible" feature is System Settings. [Some folk say](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/11348/17907) that will solve the mysterious problem of *Disk not ejected properly* error messages that plague some of us with external Time Machine drives.

I cannot find that feature now in macOS Sonoma’s *System Settings* panels. The [feature is mentioned](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/MCHLFC3B7879/14.0/mac/14.1.1) as *Put hard disks to sleep when possible* in the Help files.

Where does one find "Put the hard disk(s) to sleep when possible" in [System Settings](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-system-settings-mh15217/mac) in [macOS Sonoma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Sonoma)?

Comment: You're sure you have a mechanical hard drive attached?

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, this option is available under "Energy Saver" on my Mac Mini:

[image]

... but there is no Energy Saver panel on my MacBook Pro, and it is missing from the Battery panel.

This Apple Support document suggests that it should be under the Options dialog in the Battery panel for laptops, so I presume it's a bug.

https://support.apple.com/lv-lv/guide/mac-help/mchle41a6ccd/mac

Or perhaps it only appears when a mechanical drive is plugged in?

However, running `pmset -g` to get the current power settings, I find that both the Mini and laptop have `disksleep` set to 10, which would suggest that it is already set on both.